# How many Megami Tensei timelines are there?

Tags: megami-tensei

The [*Megami Tensei*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megami_Tensei) games and their many spinoffs have some obvious linkages - for example *Shin Megami Tensei 2* directly follows *Shin Megami Tensei 1*; the *Persona 2* duology directly follows *Persona: Revelations*.

But some are obviously alternate timelines, e.g. *Shin Megami Tensei III: Nocturne* and *Digital Devil Saga*, as well as some endings for *Strange Journey*, all portray incompatible ends-of-the-world.

Which games are canonically in the same universes, which games are in compatible universes, and between which games do the timelines diverge?

Answer (score 1):

There is no official confirmation about the timelines, so I can only give you information based on popular belief. Just keep in mind that all of Megami Tensei endings are canon, that includes SMT games too. Here it is:

Digital Devil Novels MT and Warrior of the Demon City >> Megami tensei 1 >> Megami Tensei 2.
I think MT 2 happened after SMT 1 then >> SMT 2 but I'm not really sure.

Below are Shin Megami Tensei games:

DS Raidou Kuzunoha 1 >> DS Raidou Kuzunoha 2 (Law Ending) >> SMT 1 (Neutral) >> SMT Nine and Imagine >> SMT 2

DS Raidou Kuzunoha 1 >> DS Raidou Kuzunoha 2 (Neutral Ending) >> SMT If... >> Persona 1 >> Devil Summoner >> Soul Hackers >> Persona 2 IS

DS Raidou Kuzunoha 1 >> DS Raidou Kuzunoha 2 (Neutral Ending) >> SMT If... >> P1 (Ice Queen Quest good ending) >> Devil Summoner >> Soul Hackers >> P2 EP >> P3 >> P4 >> P4 Arena

DS Raidou Kuzunoha 1 >> DS Raidou Kuzunoha 2 (Chaos Ending) >> Nocturne (Neutral) >> Strange Journey

DS Raidou Kuzunoha 1 >> DS Raidou Kuzunoha 2 (Chaos Ending) >> Nocturne (True Demon Ending) somehow the demon world is connected to the events in SMT imagine and SMT 2

That's all as far as I know. It could be wrong though. The rest is up to you.